# Regex replace special characters with hyphen except first and last

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regular expression to format song names to url friendly aliases. It replaces 1 or more consecutive instances of special characters and white space with a hyphen.

```
$alias = preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", "-", trim(strtolower($name)));
```

This works fine so if the song name was `This is *is* a (song) NAME` it would create the alias `this-is-a-song-name`. But if the name has special characters at the beginning or end `*This is a song (name)` it would create `-this-is-a-song-name-` creating hyphens at each end.

How can I modify the regex to replace as it is above, but to replace the first and last special character with empty space.

Comment: Have you thought about using a second filter which trims hyphens from the head and tail of the string if they are present?

Comment: Yes definitely thought about it but I'd like try and see if it's possible to do it in one regex statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a double replacement.

```
$str = '*This is a song (name)';
$s   = preg_replace('~^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$~', '', $str);
echo preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '-', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform that in 2 steps:

- In the first step, you remove special characters at the beginning and at the end of your string
- In the second step, you reuse your regex as it is now.

The code could look like this:

```
$alias = preg_replace("/(^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$)/", "", trim(strtolower($name));
$alias = preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", "-", $alias);
```

(I haven't tested it but you may get the idea)